Astro with Alpine.js: what's the right syntax to parameterize client scripts?
I have installed Astro with Alpine.js integration.
The following code snippet works fine, but I would like to parameterize the URL.
<div x-data="{
            result: null,
            async retrieveData() {
            this.result = await (await fetch('https://api.sampleapis.com/coffee/hot')).text(); 
            }
        }"
        x-init="retrieveData()"
    >
        <span x-text="result"></span>
    </div>

...but the following code doesn't work.
---
const URL='https://api.sampleapis.com/coffee/hot'
---
<div x-data="{
            result: null,
            async retrieveData() {
            this.result = await (await fetch({URL})).text(); 
            }
        }"
        x-init="retrieveData()"
    >
        <span x-text="result"></span>
    </div>

Any suggestions?

I would like to put the url string of the first snippet in a js var (see the second snippet)
